# How to change the Add To Cart Woocommerce button to a customized URL that pulls in the product SKU and Quantity#

Tags: wordpress, url, woocommerce, product-quantity, sku

In my Woocommerce store, I want to change all of the 'Add to Cart' buttons to an external URL that dynamically pulls in the product's SKU and Quantity. The URL would be something similar to this:
https://www.custom-url.com/{SKU}/{QUANTITY}

This is for a Woocommerce site that will no longer have purchasing available on their end. Instead, they're going to be using a completely different vendor for purchasing on the vendor's site. Therefore I need each product's 'Add to Cart' button to have this link that automatically adds that product to the cart on the vendor's site. That link is already set up to do what it needs to do on the vendor's side. I just need help figuring out how to change the link on the Woocommerce side.

Say there's a product with a SKU of 234275 and the customer wants 2 of them so they select 2 from the quantity option. I need the Add to Cart button for that product changed to this: https://www.custom-url.com/234275/2

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that works for you.

The only problem you will face if you change the quantity it most process and AJAX request and should refresh.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link_updated', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link_updated( $link, $product ){
    $quantity = isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1;
    $link = sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button product_type_%s">%s</a>',
    esc_url( home_url( '/').$product->get_id() . '/' . $quantity ),
    esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
    esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
    esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
    esc_attr( $product->get_type() ),
    esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
);
return $link;
```

}

Moreover, the home_url() that i have placed should be replaced with external URL of the site.

Hope it works for you as of your requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code, however, when I put it in my child theme's function file, the page almost loads and then it stops and shows a blank page that says HTTP ERROR 500. Any ideas as to why?

I was supposed to replace just the '/' of the home_url, correct?

"
esc_url( home_url( 'http://www.customurl.com/').$product->get_id() . '/' . $quantity ),

Comment: @ChelseyWesterman Nope, You should replace home_url() to http://customurl.com
Like: esc_url( 'http://customurl.com/'.$product->get_id() . '/' . $quantity )

Comment: Ok, I've updated that but it's still not working. This code goes in my child theme's function.php file, correct? Here's the only line of code that I changed with the actual url I'm using:   
 esc_url( 'https://www.summitracing.com/cart/vendoradd/scegaskets/sce-'.$product->get_id() . '/' . $quantity ),

Comment: I figured it out! There wasn't a closing } bracket. Thank you so much for your help!